# Cannot use Clojure 1.7 with Leiningen

Tags: clojure, leiningen

Using Leiningen, I'm unable to use Clojure 1.7 in project, but I am able to use later versions.

For instance, if I clone down the [Om Next Tutorial](https://github.com/awkay/om-tutorial) and try to run it, I get a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: clojure/lang/Tuple`. [Full stack trace here](https://pastebin.com/2LaHQazw). A similar error occurs any time I try to use Clojure 1.7 in a project with Leiningen.

However, the error goes away if I upgrade to Clojure `1.8` or `1.9` in `project.clj`. The trouble is that I'm not always in a position to upgrade the version on a project.

Versions installed:

- Clojure: `1.8.0`
- Java: `OpenJDK 1.8.0_171`
- Leiningen: `2.8.1`
- Ubuntu: `16.04 LTS`

The problem happens with or without my lien `profiles.clj`.

I'm not a Java expert, but this looks like a classpath issue to me. I am using `update-java-alternatives` to set the path to Java 1.8.

**Edit**: I created a minimal repo that reproduced the problem, using the very first part of the Om Next tutorial, [here](https://github.com/jejy2343/clj17-repro).

Comment: The class the stacktrace complains about is there for some long time (and was in 1.7).  Please provide the full, minimal example, that shows the error (e.g. your project.clj and your src/hawk/core.cljs)

Comment: In your stack trace, the issue is caused by figwheel_sidecar. Which version of figwheel do you use. You can see this links for more details: https://clojurians-log.clojureverse.org/dirac/2016-01-28

Comment: @cfrick: I added a minimal reproduction. It just follows the very first part of the Om Next tutorial, so I'm pretty sure it's not a version mismatch (unless that tutorial is wrong).

Comment: @MinhTuanNguyen - Using the example repository, I am using figwheel-sidecar "0.5.16", which is what the Om Next tutorial requires.

Comment: Managed to fix this by doing two things: removing and reinstalling lein and changing the versions of figwheel sidecar. Thanks for the pointers -- they put me on the right direction.

Comment: Can you add your final version as a solution? Also clarify Clojure 1.7 vs 1.8, etc.

Comment: I did two things to get it to work. The first was fully remove and reinstall Leiningen. The second was to switch to switch the figwheel-sidecar version to "0.5.0-SNAPSHOT". After that, I was able to use Clojure 1.7 (1.8 worked the whole time).